# Javascript scaling page content with window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my webpage, I'm using Javascript to responsively change the layout of the page elements. Originally, I had the script with`if (window.innerWidth > 768)` within a resize event listener to act like a CSS media query, and that worked smoothly. The layout changed responsively as expected when resizing across the 768 pixel threshold.

Then I decided to change the if statement to `if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight)` to change the layout of the page elements when the viewport width is greater than the height and vice versa. However, whenever I resized the page to trigger a layout change, the page just freezes up and turns black. Yet when I refresh the page, it loads up perfectly fine with the resized layout. It seems that only manual change of the window size will cause the page to freeze.

What is the reason behind this behavior? Is my code just really inefficient?

Here's my resize listener function:

```js
function resizeListener(){
  //selectors
  let sections = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('section'));
  let items = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('section-item'));
  let heads = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('header'));
  let descs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('description'));

  let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  //window width > height
  if (windowWidth > windowHeight){
    //grid layout
    sections.forEach((x)=>{
      x.style.display = "grid";
    });
    items.forEach((x)=>{
      x.style.width = "auto";
      x.style.maxWidth = "none";
      x.style.height = "auto";
      x.style.margin = "0";
      let img = x.childNodes[0];
      img.style.width = "auto";
      img.style.height = "100%";
    });
    //if width big enough, let window height decide styling
    if (windowWidth > windowHeight * 1.6){
      sections.forEach((x)=>{
        x.style.height = "100vh";
        x.style.width = "160vh";
      });
    }
    //else let window width decide styling
    else {
      sections.forEach((x)=>{
        x.style.height = "62.5vw"
        x.style.width = "100vw";
      });
    }
    //style text according to height
    let headRatio = 0.032;
    let descRatio = 0.021;
    let lineRatio = 0.053;
    heads.forEach((x)=>{
      x.style.fontSize = (x.parentNode.offsetHeight * headRatio) + 'px';
    });
    descs.forEach((x)=>{
      let height = x.parentNode.offsetHeight;
      x.style.fontSize = (height * descRatio) + 'px';
      x.style.lineHeight = (height * lineRatio) + 'px';
    });
  }

  //window height > width
  else {
    sections.forEach((x)=>{
      x.style.display = "flex";
      x.style.height = "auto";
      x.style.width = "100vw";
    });
    items.forEach((x)=>{
      x.style.width = "300px";
      x.style.maxWidth = "90%";
      x.style.height = "auto";
      x.style.margin = "10px";
      let img = x.childNodes[0];
      img.style.width = "100%";
      img.style.height = "auto";
    });
    heads.forEach((x)=>{
      x.style.fontSize = "24px";
    });
    descs.forEach((x)=>{
      x.style.fontSize = "14px";
      x.style.lineHeight = "28px";
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue. Can you add an example where this is reproducable? A link to a fiddle maybe? What browsers have the issue for you?

Comment: Looks like the browser is repainting too much and it cause to freeze it, maybe try to avoid that kind of performance issue by reducing the number of valid cases

Comment: @Sirence The freezing is happening in Chrome. I just tested on Edge and it doesn't freeze, but there is a small space where window.innerWidth is slightly bigger than window.innerHeight and the image elements on the page get super enlarged, which I think is where chrome is having the loading issue.

Comment: @Sirence Okay I fixed the issue. I had a leftover css media query I had forgotten about that was interfering with the Javascript scaling. The freezing was happening because the css was causing the images to load at enormous scales, and Chrome couldn't handle it well on my computer. Rookie mistake!